# Is using the word "singular" to describe someone or something unique an outdated adjective?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, archaicisms

Is using the word "singular" to describe someone or something unique an outdated adjective?

E.g.

> By a **singular** piece of good fortune, Mr. Athelney Jones, the
>   well-known member of the detective police force, happened to be at the
>   Norwood Police Station, and was on the ground within half an hour of
>   the first alarm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's example *singular piece of good fortune* (or [luck](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=singular%20piece%20of%20good%20luck&year_start=1901&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)) is a "stock phrase" that accounts for a significant proportion of all instances of *singular piece*, which is clearly a declining usage...

[image: .]

I don't think the "literal" meaning of *singular* as *unique* applies very often at all. It normally means just *odd, unusual, unexpected*. Usage [has declined](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=singular&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), so OP is right to suspect it's "dated".

On the other hand, [singularity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Singularity.html), which also had its heyday in the early 1800s, is coming back up again [in recent decades](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=singularity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Doubtless partly because of mathematical singularities such as [black holes](http://www.kidsastronomy.com/black_hole.htm), and my personal favourite, [The Technological Singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity). Notwithstanding that Wikipedia link, I define this as the day when technological advance becomes so rapid that *literally*, yesterday's "magic" is today's "routine science", every 24 hours.

Comment: Is the rarity of "singular piece" merely due to the kind of contexts in which we use "piece of"? For instance, a pie has many "pieces of pie", and no matter which one I'm eating, I'd expect the others to be of comparable quality. =)

Comment: @rakslice: it's 'piece of __cake__' and 'easy as __pie__'. Piea come in _slices_, not pieces.

Comment: @rakslice: Per my *has declined* link above, I'm in no doubt the "flowery" use of **singular** to mean "unusual" has itself declined. But if/when it's [still] used, it often occurs with *piece of good fortune/luck*.

Comment: There (is/was?) also [singular stroke of](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=singular+stroke+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) good/bad fortune/luck, which seems a little less dated to me, but even so, most current usages discard the word *singular*.

Comment: I guess it is yet another one of those Victorian nuances that has failed to stand the test of time.

Comment: I don't understand how the declining use of _singular piece_, as shown in the graph, answers the question about the use of _singular_ to describe someone or something unique. Isn't _singular piece_ just one singular example? What am I missing here?

Comment: @sarah: I'm not sure - perhaps you missed the specific meaning being discussed. A *singular piece* is a **unique** or in popular parlance **very unusual** piece. It's not the same as a **single** piece. In grammar and certain other contexts, *singular* contrasts with *plural*, but that's not the usage we're talking about here - which can't really be used in **just** *one singular example*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, although I sometimes use it myself in the comfort of my own home. It is perhaps particularly associated with Jane Austen, as in this, for example, from 'Northanger Abbey':

> . . . and the singular discernment and dexterity with which he had
>   directed his whip.

Of course, the noun, *singularity*, now does service in an astrophysical context.